# PHP and Mysql special chars

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

i haven't found the answer at this question browsing around so i guess asking it's ok...

My php code reads from my Mysql Database a string and prints it, here is the code

```
$sql2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Corsi WHERE Nome='$Ln_1[Ln_1]'");
$Ln_1_a = mysql_fetch_array($sql2);
$Ln_1_descr = $Ln_1_a[5];
```

But special chars, such as 'è' 'à' 'ò' etc. are printed as '�'.
My Mysql Encoding is utf8 and also in my html header i have utf8 encoding, so what is wrong with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, at the start of your MySQL connection after database selection you should put this query:

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
```

Then be sure, your page has encoding `UTF-8` (I guess you are using HTML, so it should looks like:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

) and also your script file must be saved in `UTF8` encoding.

But I have to remind `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and you should use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead with [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/2811746) due to safety of your queries.

Answer (score 1):

Try (after mysql_connect) do `mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8')`. And also check, if font support these characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) function

like this

```
$Ln_1_descr = utf8_decode($Ln_1_a[5]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `htmlspecialchars($yourvariable, ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8")`

Also verify your MySQL configure file has:

[client]
default-character-set=UTF-8

[mysql]
default-character-set=UTF-8

Also, utf8_encode() and utf8_decode() would work for you as well.